# Logo, images and mp3 are not loading in my github website (made with visual studio code)

Tags: html, image, github, mp3, html5-audio

For my full-stack program, I need to make three html pages and upload them in Github and make it an online website. Everything is working, except for the logo, images and audio which is a mp3 file.

I made a main file, called homework. The mainfile contains 3 subfiles which are Images, Audio and Movie and three html pages. In these subfiles I saved the images and audio.

This is the website: https://baomazing.github.io/nha_huiswerkopdracht_les9/

See below codes:

```
**Logo:**
<center><img src="Afbeeldingen/logo.png" width="200" height="200" alt="logo" title="Plaswijckpark logo"></center>


**Images:
**<img src="Afbeeldingen/Ingang.jpeg" width="300" height="200"></image>
<img src="Afbeeldingen/Treintje.jpeg" width="300" height="200"></image>
<img src="Afbeeldingen/Waterpret.jpeg" width="300" height="200"</image>
                
**Audio:
**<audio controls src="Geluiden/fun-life-112188.mp3"></audio>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I tried to change the file names into .html but that didnt work. I also tried to upload the single image and audio files + html pages all together, didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

According to me,
there can be multiple reasons for not loading all the i-frames into your GitHub pages. Some of them are mentioned below:

1. GitHub is case sensitive so, you can check your spellings of the path.
2. Make sure your audios and videos are uploaded to your GitHub before you host them.
3. It seems that you have kept your audios and videos in the folder called "Afbeeldingen" so, see that it contains them before hosting your webpage.
4. In the least case, your internet connection is poor and they are not loading.